# How many intents can receive a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, sqlite, service

I have a Bluetooth Service that receive values every second, and a GPS Service that receive a location every 10 seconds. All those datas must be stocked in a database. To avoid that those 2 services try to write at the same time in the database, I created a Database Service to store those datas: Bluetooth and GPS Services send their values into broadcast to this Service, and this Service will stock them. I have a few questions:

-How many broadcasts per second can receive my Database? (with a Broadcast Receiver)
- If my Database Service receive a new value but haven't had the time store the previous one, what happen?

Comment: I don't know about the number of broadcast one can receive per second, however for your second question, the easiest would probably be to have a `Queue` for the events. Each time your db receives an event, it puts it in a queue. You then have a Thread that runs in the background, and deals with the `Queue` to insert elements one by one. This way, you do not loose any information you wanna store, and ensure each element is inserted in the same order as it was received

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your database in a `ContentProvider` implementation.  Normally they are used when you want to be able to expose your data outside of your app, but it also provides a central, well documented API for accessing structured data.  You can protect your database access within the methods of the content provider (e.g. `insert()`, `delete()`, etc.)  The initial `ContentResolver` usage to get to the provider is the biggest context switch hit you should have.  After that, the binder connection behind the scenes will short-circuit and stay within the same process.

Any time you send an `Intent`, the system has to communicate to the `ActivityManagerService` running in the `system_server` process.  This context switch is extra overhead you don't need and can avoid.  Additionally, no need for a queue.  Just protect your database access within the provider implementation.

Comment: The database will be protected, there can be only one Service that can write. But if an another Service try to write, the request will be rejected or the Service wait?
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. Using two services is probably more complexity than you need.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English
I have 2 services: one for Bluetooth, one for GPS/stepcounter, and both need to write in database. 
If I understood, with a Content Provider the database is always protected, even if 2 services try to write simultaneously?
My question is: if BluetoothService is writing, and the GPS Service want to write(for example), the database will be protected if I understood, but what happen? The GPS Service will wait until the first write is finished or it doesn't write(GPS need to retry to write)?

Comment: The database will only be protected when using the ContentProvider, if your implementation properly handles mutual exclusion.  The same would apply if you use a wrapper around the SQLite APIs (which is also perfectly valid, as long as you're using a static instance in the same app.)  So yes, with the mutual exclusion in place one service would effectively wait for the other to finish its write (by waiting on a lock) before it would be allowed to write.